# IntelliJ Build does not execute sbt 'compile' dependencies

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am new to IntelliJ/SBT area so I might be missing obvious things.
However, after a lot of googling I couldn't find an answer to my question.
So here it is:

I have set up IntelliJ (version 2017.3.5) with sbt and everything works fine (almost). In my `build.sbt` file my `compile` command depends on another command that generates a bash script. The rule looks like this:

```
compile := (compile in Compile).dependsOn(script).value
```

I can enter the sbt environment from the command line (not from IntelliJ yet) and execute the `compile` command and everything works as expected. So far so good.

However, when I open my project with IntelliJ and I press the `Build` button, my project gets built with sbt (I can see it in the sbt shell window that opens at the bottom) but I do not get my script. If I run the `compile` command explicitly from the - already open for me - sbt window, I do get my script.

Why doesn't this work with the `Build` button in IntelliJ ?

My platform is MacOS. I can provide more details if needed.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get the required behaviour in version 2018.1.3 and SBT 1.1.5 by

1. Open sbt projects tool window: `View | Tool Windows | sbt`
2. Click `sbt settings` icon
3. Select `Use sbt shell for build and import (required sbt 0.13.5+)`

As always, if IntelliJ is misbehaving try the nuke options:

- `Invalidate caches \ Restart...`
- `rm -fr .idea` and re-import the project

Alternatively, we can create a custom [run configuration](https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started-intellij-track/building-a-scala-project-with-intellij-and-sbt.html#running-the-project):

1. `Run | Edit configurations`
2. Click `+` button and select `SBT Task`
3. Name it `Build project`
4. In the `Tasks` field, type `compile`
5. Click `OK`
6. `Run | Run 'Build project'`

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunately, upgrading to version 2018.1.3 introduces some other issues (i.e., `Cannot determine module type (SBT_MODULE)`) so I will stick with 2017 for now at least. In that version, the suggested changes still don't work (except for the last one which I can live with :) ). My sbt version btw is 1.1.1.

Comment: Regarding this error you have to update/install IntelliJ Scala plugin after IntelliJ upgrade. Core IntelliJ and its plugins unfortunatelly do not update at the same time.

Comment: Yup, exactly ! I actually figured that out :). Thanks again !